# The ejs code does not give an output [EJS]

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, ejs

I have a problem. I'm writing a panel for my discord bot, I'm using ejs. The server is based on the express and passport library. The problem is that I want to display the name of the mysql database but I am not getting the result in the browser and with other results the result is displayed. Please help. I'm posting the code.

main.ejs

```
<%= server.guild_id %> <!-- 76593313568....704  -->

<% database.sql("SHOW DATABASES", 0, (rows) => { %>
   <%= rows[0].Database %> <!-- nothing -->
<% }) %>
```

dashboard.js - route

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const database = require('./../database/database.js')

[...]

res.render('dashboard/server/main', {
    guilds: req.user.guilds,
    servers: rows,
    user: req.user,
    admin: false,
    points: 0,
    server: server,
    database: database
})
```

If I use the `console.log` code, I can see the database without any problems

Comment: dont you think you are mising a < at line 3

Comment: I had to delete it by accident on stackoverflow, but my code is fine

Comment: start by not putting business logic in your EJS, put that in your Javascript. Get `database.sql(...)` first and _then_ render the response (either in its callback, or if it supports promises, after `await`ing the db response). You template should have all the data it needs to render already, it's not going to wait for callbacks or promises.